# Marketing cloud synchronized contacts reduced by half

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact-deletion

Something strange happened today. We have Marketing cloud connect and we had 107,000 contacts being synched from the Contacts object in SF to the synched_DE in MC.

Prior to setting up Connect, we had contacts being imported through an automation. This import was loading contacts into a different DE which had roughly 80,000 of them. This automation was paused when we established the connection between SF and MC.

Seeing how its paused i went ahead and deleted the contacts in this DE but now our synched Contacts have reduced from 107,000 to 56,000. There are no additional filters added to the sync. It was never paused. No changes made at CRM.

Question:
How can me deleting contacts from a legacy DE impact synchronized contact numbers.
any insights on this is appreciated.

Comment: Did you use Contact Deletion to delete the records in your Data Extensions, or simply clear the records?

Comment: I used contact deletion

Comment: I must add that the synched contacts count is very very slowly going up. At 3:30pm we had 57,000 synchronized contacts. 4 hours later we have 60,150. we are still 40,000 shy of what should be synched.

Comment: Deleting contacts from a data extension using contact deletion functionality removes all instances of their Contact Key/Subscriber key from all Sendable Data Extensions. Your Contact_Salesforce, Lead_Salesforce and User_Salesforce data extensions are Sendable, so records in these data extensions will also be deleted. Touch the CRM records in some way, like doing an import using a Data Loader and they'll flow back through Data Stream and end up back in your synchronised data, once the Suppression Period you've selected for Contact Deletion passes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that contact deletion is the least prioritized process in the SFMC backend, so before even the point when contacts are suppressed on a specified period, then they have to be processed. By least prioritized I mean that all Automations, Journeys, communications and etc. should be processed, and only in the "idle time" contacts deletion would continue to process.

To check the status you have to go to the parent BU and go to the Contact Builder, then either in:

1. All Contact tab --> Click on trash bin icon and select "View Pending Deletions" ([documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_cab_delete_contact.htm&type=5))
2. Contacts Analytics tab --> Select day/week/month tab and click on the pie chart --> See the progress of contact deletion (better if you have several deletion requests to see the visualized results)

Moreover, based on your updated info in the last comment, it looks like you just need to wait until when the contact deletion process would be fully finished, and only then you would be able to re-introduce contacts to the SFMC.

Comment: Contacts deletion has completed as a process. I had no wait time for suppression so it went straight to delete. The issue is when I did this I ended up losing contacts from my synchronized DE as well which I am confused about. The contacts I deleted were in a different DE which was being imported daily before we had the MC connection. This daily import was paused in November last year so I thought it is ok to delete them because our contacts are synched now every 15 mins.

Comment: Contact deletion process does not affect Synchronized Data Extensions in order to delete records from there, you need to delete them first in CRM, and only then with the next refresh, they would disappear from Synced DE.

Are those different DEs were sendable and with the correct relationship to SubscriberKey when you were deleting contacts?

Comment: That is what I thought. I have raised a case with salesforce. Yes to delete them I loaded the subscriber keys into a DE which was send able using subscriber key. I then did the Contact delete from Contact Builder.

Comment: My bad, I actually missed one point. I meant that contacts from Synced DE could be deleted generally by the contact deletion process, the thing is that they will come back after some time. If you already had Synced DEs set and pushed the deletion button, those contacts were actually deleted and then added back but with 32 digit UUID ([article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5)) Can you check that?

Comment: so after checking the contacts are re synching from salesforce. the Contact key is the same as it was before. But this is happening at a snails pace. In the last 24 hours roughly 8,000 contacts got added. Is it normal for the re synch to take this long?

Comment: no, we got around 24 mils of records re-synced from one object within 4-5 hours. I guess the correct way to proceed at this point is to talk with SF Support and see what is happening on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

So I finished speaking to support. There was an issue.

1. I had to activate tenant specific end points. There was an update about this a few months ago.
2. After doing this, I did an object refresh which brought them all back into MC.

I was told to delete subscribers from DE and not Contact delete if I do not want the associated information for that contact lost.